# Under what conditions is this true: $\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{r} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(r,x) dx = 2\pi f(0,0)$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I will like to know under what hypothesis the following is true, and maybe a sketch of the proof. I saw it in a solution of an exercise. In this exercise, $f$ was harmonic, but I don't know if that is necessary for the limit to be true.

> $$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{r} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(r,x) dx = 2\pi f(0,0)$$

Thank you!

Comment: If $f(r,x) = 1$ is constant, this is false.

Comment: are you sure that is what you want to ask?  If the example was a harmonic, then I would assume the mean-value property ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property ) was used.

Comment: Let g(r,x)=f(r,2.pi - x) and apply this to g. The LHS is the same,but the RHS is now g(0,0)/2pi, which is f(0,2pi)/2pi.